How can I set all form fields readonly in Odoo 16 depending on a field?
In Odoo 16, I'm trying to make all fields from a form view readonly depending on the value of other field of the same form.
First I've tried the following:
<xpath expr="//field" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('my_field', '=', True)]}</attribute>
</xpath>

With no result.
I can't use <form edit="false"> neither since I have to check the field value.
A rule with <field name="perm_write">1</field> works, but it doesn't behave as I need, since it allows you to modify the whole form until you click on Save and get the permission error.
And overwriting get_view is not a valid option, since cannot depend on my_field value.
The only solution I can find is to modify each field of the form with xpath, which is pretty disturbing, and is not consistent if in the future more fields are added to the form view via other apps.
Does anyone have a better solution for this?

What about a combination of overriding get_view and adding attrs readonly attributes? That could work, but you have to check lot of special cases like child model fields (one2many/many2many) or fields having attrs already.. In the end using XPath is the least beautiful way, but probably the only easy working one.

Oh maybe it's not that difficult, here an example how to do that: https://github.com/OCA/server-ux/commit/d67a23d833787ecbefac222c83e8a499f045eaea

@CZoellner great idea! It worked! You can post it as an answer, I'll edit that with the code I've used and set it as the right answer. Thank you!

Please help me with the same problem but with Odoo 17:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78992875/how-can-i-set-all-form-fields-readonly-in-odoo-17-depending-on-a-field

Extending get_view actually is a good idea. There is a module in server-ux repo of the OCA where something similar is done: when something is saved in a one2many field, every field in the form view will be set to readonly. To do this, the readonly modifier is rewritten for each field.
The module: base_tier_validation
The interesting part of code: get_view
Code for your case:
@api.model
def get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type="form", **options):
    res = super().get_view(
        view_id=view_id,
        view_type=view_type,
        **options,
    )
    if view_type == "form":
        doc = etree.XML(res["arch"])
        for field in doc.xpath("//field[@name][not(ancestor::field)]"):
            modifiers = json.loads(
                field.attrib.get("modifiers", '{"readonly": false}')
            )
            if modifiers.get("readonly") is not True:
                modifiers["readonly"] = OR(
                    [
                        modifiers.get(
                            "readonly", []
                        ) or [],
                        [("my_field", "=", True)],
                    ]
                )
                field.attrib["modifiers"] = json.dumps(modifiers)
        res["arch"] = etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
    return res


@forvas are you sure removing the ancestor part from the xpath is worth it?

Of course it was not a good idea, kudos to you... without the ancestor part, interacting with any one2many field (and more...) gave an Uncaught Promise error, which is obvious. Thank you again!
