How can I set all form fields readonly in Odoo 17 depending on a field?
In odoo 17, I want the formview to only view and not edit based on the value of the field order_payment_state = done.
Instead of adding the readonly attribute to each field, I want to write a python function that inherits and modifies the get_view function to readonly the entire form view based on the field value of that formview.
Please help me do this.

If you want to make a form readonly, you just have to include edit="0" when declaring your form (source), e.g.
<form edit="0">
    <!-- Your form here -->
</form>

Otherwise, if you really insist on using get_view to set all attributes, you should check out the hr_timesheet model's _get_view and maybe even the _apply_time_label methods (addons/hr_timesheet/model/hr_timesheet.py). The code is pretty much all there and then some.
In short, I think you'd just need to modify the _get_view method to do something like:
@api.model
def _get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
    arch, view = super()._get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)
    # Add on conditionals or pull additional data here. E.g. can check if you only want to make certain view_types readonly.
    for node in arch.xpath("//field"):
        node.set('readonly', "1")
    return arch, view

A word of caution is that if you do this in python and deploy, you're not going to be able to make the fields editable without removing said python code, as opposed to edit="0", which can be toggled ad-hoc via Odoo's debug menu, unless that's what you are going for.
Hope this helps.
Update:
After a little bit more experimenting, this is the closest I got to dynamically setting readonly attributes on all fields. The only caveat to this method is that it sets the readonly attribute to ALL fields, meaning if you have a relational field like a One2many and have defined a tree view for it within your form, you would need to edit the xpath to not select these fields, especially if you include an additional that checks for a field that is not present in the relation's model.
@api.model
def _get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
    arch, view = super()._get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)
    if view_type == "form":
        for node in arch.xpath("//field"):
            node.set("readonly", "id == 75")
    return arch, view


Thank you for the solution, let me ask a little more, my desired condition is that if the record has sublevel_id.level in [ 'L5.1', ​​'L7.2'] then I want to readonly that whole form, I The difficulty is: initially I wanted to get the active_id so I could get the data of sublevel_id.level, but I failed due to the fact that when I went to view the formview details of any record, it was not in self.env.context. There is no active_id, so what should I do in my case?

I think there are many ways to approach this. If you want to lock down the whole form with that condition, you can utilize the above _get_view and just add the check before setting the fields to readonly. If you want to add active_id to context, you can do so in whatever action you use to access your form by including a  and try adding the fields you need there.

If you could also elaborate how you are accessing this record, it would be more helpful, e.g. clicking on the record from a Tree view or from a button.

I clicked the record from the tree view, can you edit the get_view function code so I can see, based on the condition sublevel_id.level in ['L5.1', ​​'L7.2'], I got tried but failed

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post so I'll do it here. Please post your error logs as well otherwise its impossible to diagnose. As per your question tag, you're using Odoo 17 where readonly no longer accepts domains, it just accepts a normal python statement so that could be a cause

Edited cos it turns out _get_view still uses domains (TIL).

Please review the code I have edited to your liking. It seems the function is not working correctly

I edited the function like you, and it is having readonly viewview for all records including records that do not satisfy the condition, think "[('sublevel_id.level', 'in', ['L5.1 ', 'L7.2'])]" doesn't seem to work so it automatically assigns all records to readonly formview

Oh yea I guess it doesn't actually work. It just interprets anything that is not "false" or "0" to be true...I guess there is no easy way to do it. I wasn't able to figure out at which point of rendering do field values get accessed and checked but it is likely that it is in the FormRenderer.js file in the "web" module but at that point you might as well use Owl-components to make a completely custom view.

Basically, as mentioned before, you would have to convert your domain to a normal python statement, i.e. sublevel_id.level in ['L5.1', 'L7.2']. However, also know that in Odoo forms, you can't access fields within relational fields directly. You'd probably have to include a sublevel_level = fields.Char(related="sublevel_id.level") in your model and do the check on this field instead. Naturally this field would have to be provided as an invisible field in your form view as well.

I tested with your example node.set("readonly", "id == 75"), it runs completely correctly, only readonly for the id I set, but why if I replace that condition with my condition is "[('sublevel.level', 'in', ['L5.1', ​​'L7.2'])]" then it works wrong, it readonly all records, Didn't even check my set conditions

Again, you cant use the domain arrays [] and tuples () in Odoo 17. You have to use a python statement like sublevel.level in ['L5.1', 'L7.2']. When you call node.set, you are directly setting attributes into the form view.
